# How to recognise a date diff within a partition?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a report that summarises the spend in each week of the year and also returns the spend from the same week in the previous year in BigQuery

I cant understand why my partition to filter on previous year is not correctly calculating the amount - it continues to return current year spend

I've searched google to try to understand why this might not be working but came up blank.

I have this line which will return the correct spend for the week/year

```
SUM(Gross_home_currency) OVER (PARTITION BY  Brand_Family,EXTRACT(week from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)),EXTRACT(year from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date))) AS WeekSales
```

And a similar line where i ask it to look for contracts with a date 1 year prior.

```
SUM(Gross_home_currency) OVER (PARTITION BY  Brand_Family,EXTRACT(week from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)),EXTRACT (year from DATE_SUB(CAST(Customer_Contract_date as date), INTERVAL 1 Year)) AS LastYearWeekSales,
```

It runs without an issue but then the value for LastYearWeekSales is equal to the current years which makes me think that the date calculation did not get applied.

If any one knows why this has happened or could point me in the direction to better understand this that would be great.

---

[Example output & column i'm trying to output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uQPs.png)

(Select
Year,
Week,
Brand_Family,
WeekSales,
Sum(WeekSales) over (PARTITION BY  Brand_Family,year order by year,week ASC) as CumulativeSales,
Lag(WeekSales,1) over (PARTITION BY  Brand_Family,year order by year,week asc) AS LastWeek

From

(SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(week from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)) as Week,Brand_Family,SUM(Gross_home_currency) OVER (PARTITION BY  Brand_Family,EXTRACT(week from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)),EXTRACT(year from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date))) AS WeekSales,EXTRACT(year from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)) as Year

FROM exampletable cc
where
cc.Customer_Contract_Status="Processed in ISOP"
and 
cc. Brand_Family in ("CB") 
and
cc. Contract_Type="Sponsorship"
and EXTRACT(year from PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',Customer_Contract_date)) in (2018,2019)
order by 1  ))

Comment: Adding a date_sub in the partition will not move your window to the sales from the previous year. Include a complete query and some sample of data.

Comment: Check out the `window_clause` section here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#window-clause .

Comment: Hi ECris - have added the complete query and a sample of the output data - as far as i understand it the partition window will have the sales from the previous year (or should return null if no previous year/week row)

Comment: Also thanks Rthenha for the link windows clause sounds like what i need but dont know how to tie the result of the windowed data set which i have to a preceding rows value